# obtener array de post en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Que tal tengo este codigo de WP

```php
while ( have_posts() ) {
    $i++;
    if ( $i > 1 ) {
        echo '<hr class="post-separator styled-separator is-style-wide section-inner" aria-hidden="true" />';
    }
    the_post();
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
}
```

Como puedo obtener el array de categorias de los post en este codigo?

Comment: Hechale un vistazo a  la funcion wp_get_post_categories

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!